# TcpCatcher: send HTTP request from hook

Tags: http, network-programming

Is it possible, with [TcpCatcher](http://www.tcpcatcher.org/index.php) to send an HTTP request *from* a custom hook (a Java class)? I know the GUI let someone edit and resend any given request, but I want this process to be automatic on certain conditions (and log the results, etc.)

So, I know it's possible, but no documentation for it. I'm asking if anyone had done this, or know how to do this? I'm looking at the `tcpcatcher.jar` file, but many classes are named `a.class`, `b.class`, etc. So if the knowledge exists somewhere around this community, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

TcpCatcher allows you to provide your own java class and calls it when an HTTP packet goes though the proxy.
You can do anything within the hook including sending an other HTTP request (but why would you want do that by the way ?)
Here is an example of a synchronous hook (it allows you to modify the packet on the fly)
http://www.tcpcatcher.org/hook_to_change_html.php
just implement the "modifyPacket" method

If you do not intend to modify the packet on the fly, you can prefer an asynchronous hook.
Here is an example :
http://www.tcpcatcher.org/logging.php

Comment: I know how to modify the packet on the fly, I wanted to know how to "create" a request *from* the hook; meaning take an ongoing request, intercept the response but instead of letting the response through, send a custom request, wait for the response and *then* let the first request through. Never mind why. The question was how to create a request from the hook, like you can do from the user interface.